# How do I solve this php is_dir code?

Tags: php

I have a folder in my website named GameUploads and I am trying to use is_dir to test if it's is a directory, which I assumed meant the same as folder.  The php code I run is in .../php/test.php and the folder I'm trying to reach is .../GameUploads/ where '...' is the url to the webpage.  My code is here:

```
//initiate file check
  $check_dir = "../../GameUploads/";

  if(is_dir($check_dir)){
    echo "$check_dir is a directory";
  }
  else{
    echo "$check_dir is not a directory";
  }

  clearstatcache();
```

I'm not sure what I was trying to do with `$check_dir` but originally is was just `.../GameUploads` which returned false, and then I entered `$check_dir='..'` which returned true.  I guess I'm trying to find a way to check if GameUploads is a directory from the php file.  How can I do this?  I'm not quite understanding how to use `is_dir` very well...  I have already read through php.net and w3schools

Comment: `is_dir()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php *"Tells whether the filename is a directory"* - What exactly are you trying to do; are you trying to check if "it exists" instead? If so `file_exists()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php *"Checks whether a file or directory exists"*.

Comment: ya I just read through file_exists on php.net as well and I tried experimenting with that, however to no avail.  I used `$check_dir='.../GameUploads'`.  '...' being my website url and then the folder I'm trying to detect.  It still returns false

Comment: *"being my website url"* - If I read that correctly, you may not be able to check for a URL. Error reporting would have warned you about that, IF that's the case here. `.../` is invalid also.. IF it does have 3 dots, use 2. `../`

Comment: Yes that is the case.  Given that, how can I check if a file exists in relativity to my website?  The file i'm trying to actually reach is dynamic and in a much deeper directory however I was just testing it on the first level and it didn't work but I'm just confused xD

Comment: try a full server path instead. I.e.: `/var/usr/public/the_folder_in_question` maybe even add a trailing slash at the end. Did you try error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yes the full server path works!  Thank you haha I am satisfied now.  I am curious now as to why the server path worked but not the website URL.  I will have to poke around but thanks again!

Comment: I'll post that as answer then so we can close 'er off ;-) glad to hear it worked out.

Comment: I posted my answer below. Someone else tried to overstep my *persistant* work here.

Comment: *"I am curious now as to why the server path worked but not the website URL"* - I have made an edit to my answer which you will have to reload and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Yes the full server path works! Thank you haha I am satisfied now. I am curious now as to why the server path worked but not the website URL. I will have to poke around but thanks again! – Pixelknight1398"*

As I stated in comments:

Use a full server path.

I.e.:

```
/var/usr/public/the_folder_in_question
```

You may have to add a trailing slash at the end.

> *"I am curious now as to why the server path worked but not the website URL."*

As per what the manual states:

*As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) to determine which wrappers support [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) family of functionality.*

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

You will need to use CURL instead, if that is available for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full server path due to $check_dir checks through the whole servers directory, and not just public forward.